# can I check my cookies to decide what page to load in RegisterRoutes

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I want to read the cookie to see if they have been to the site before and then decide where they should go at that point.

If not cookie, then load default page.

Would I handle this in the RegisterRoutes?

Here is what I currently have:

```
 public class MvcApplication : HttpApplication
  {
    public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
    {
      //filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
    }

    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {      
      routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
      routes.MapRoute(
          "Default", // Route name
          "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
          new { controller = "Account", action = "Logon", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
      );

    }

    protected void Application_Start()
    {
      AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

      RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
      RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    }
  }
```

Do I change the RegisterRoutes to decided where to go from here or would I do this elsewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you have an Action that do that? I think that would be a better way to do this. Create a Index (as the default route) action of your Controller, inside the Action, check the cookie and redirect upon the value (or if the cookie is not existing) to the route you want. This way you will be able to unit test your Action.

Let me know if you need more help or code.

Comment: good point, not sure why I didn't think of this. Guess I got focused in on the route...